# How to reduce the cache miss of a computation-intensive program

Tags: c, performance, caching, optimization

I wrote a computation-intensive program, and I profiled it with `cachegrind`, which showed the data cache miss may be the main bottleneck. I adjust(decrease the size of the computation unit to the CPU cache size) the buffer size of my program and the cache miss decrease half. But still about 5%, is there anything else I can optimize?

Before adjustment

```
==2729== 
==2729== I   refs:      20,104,725,617
==2729== I1  misses:             1,899
==2729== LLi misses:             1,835
==2729== I1  miss rate:           0.00%
==2729== LLi miss rate:           0.00%
==2729== 
==2729== D   refs:       6,754,924,837  (3,968,410,253 rd   + 2,786,514,584 wr)
==2729== D1  misses:       697,140,469  (  549,560,569 rd   +   147,579,900 wr)
==2729== LLd misses:        74,594,136  (   74,241,144 rd   +       352,992 wr)
==2729== D1  miss rate:           10.3% (         13.8%     +           5.2%  )
==2729== LLd miss rate:            1.1% (          1.8%     +           0.0%  )
==2729== 
==2729== LL refs:          697,142,368  (  549,562,468 rd   +   147,579,900 wr)
==2729== LL misses:         74,595,971  (   74,242,979 rd   +       352,992 wr)
==2729== LL miss rate:             0.2% (          0.3%     +           0.0%  )
```

After

```
==6996== I   refs:      645,316,413
==6996== I1  misses:          1,884
==6996== LLi misses:          1,628
==6996== I1  miss rate:        0.00%
==6996== LLi miss rate:        0.00%
==6996== 
==6996== D   refs:      215,556,739  (127,281,049 rd   + 88,275,690 wr)
==6996== D1  misses:      9,460,159  (  6,718,647 rd   +  2,741,512 wr)
==6996== LLd misses:         20,887  (      6,607 rd   +     14,280 wr)
==6996== D1  miss rate:         4.3% (        5.2%     +        3.1%  )
==6996== LLd miss rate:         0.0% (        0.0%     +        0.0%  )
==6996== 
==6996== LL refs:         9,462,043  (  6,720,531 rd   +  2,741,512 wr)
==6996== LL misses:          22,515  (      8,235 rd   +     14,280 wr)
==6996== LL miss rate:          0.0% (        0.0%     +        0.0%  )
```

Attached the most time-consuming function, suggested by Mysticial.
P.S. `galois_region_xor` XOR two regions of memory and `galois_w08_region_multby_2_64` does kind of thing like that, they are all time-consuming but are really optimized.

```
void shift_coding(  const GMatrixU8& mat,
             const int w,
             unsigned char * const out_buff,
             unsigned char * const in_buff,
             const unsigned long& size_in_buff ){

 unsigned int val;
 unsigned int mask_;
 unsigned int mask;
 unsigned char * pcom;
 int k = mat.cc;
 int m = mat.rr;
 unsigned long size_comp_buff = size_in_buff/k;
 bool start_2;
 unsigned char * psrc;
 unsigned char * pdes;

 pcom = (unsigned char *)malloc(size_comp_buff);
 memset(out_buff , 0 , size_in_buff*m/k);
mask_ = 1<<(w-1);

for(int j = 0 ; j < k ; ++j){
    psrc = in_buff + j*size_comp_buff;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i){
        pdes = out_buff + i*size_comp_buff;

        val = mat.ele[i*k + j];
        memset(pcom, 0, size_comp_buff);
        start_2 = false;

        if(0 == val){continue;}
        if(1 == val){galois_region_xor(psrc, pdes, pdes, size_comp_buff); continue;}

        for(mask = mask_ ; 0 < mask; mask >>=1){
            if(mask & 1){ 
                if(val & 1){ 
                    galois_region_xor(psrc , pcom , pcom , size_comp_buff);
                }
                continue;
            }
            if(0 != (val & mask)){
                start_2 = true;
                galois_region_xor(psrc , pcom , pcom , size_comp_buff);
                galois_w08_region_multby_2_64(pcom , size_comp_buff);
            }else{
                if(start_2){
                    galois_w08_region_multby_2_64(pcom , size_comp_buff);
                }
            }
        }
        galois_region_xor(pcom , pdes , pdes , size_comp_buff);
    }
}
free(pcom);
```

}

Comment: There isn't much we can do without some code. Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Can you get cachegrind to show which particular lines of code are missing cache? In particular, whether all of the misses are in the memset (which would be loading the target region into the cache), or whether they are occurring during the actual computation?

Comment: @Crashworks Thx, cachegrind shows `galois_region_xor`, `galois_w08_region_multby_2_64` and `memset` have most misses.

Comment: Not sure this is what you want to hear... but why not try manual profiling on real hardware. This works well for me, especially with fairly simple code. To manually profile, use a debugger to break in at random times and see what instruction is executing. You will probably find one or two memory access instructions are consuming much of the execution time. Once you confirm the bottle neck this way, you can work on an improvement. This technique will also find cases where branch prediction fails.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "I adjust(decrease the size of the computation unit to the CPU cache size) the buffer size of my program".  Specifically, by "CPU cache size" did you mean the *word* size or the size of the entire cache?  If the latter, I would suggest to try decreasing `size_comp_buff` even more, probably to at least around one-fourth of your total CPU cache size given your algorithm (although I'd experiment with several values in between).

Comment: @Turix I try to decrease the size of `size_in_buff` to the size of CPU's cache(which is the whole L2 cache size), and decreased it even more. The cache miss decreases when `size_in_buff` decreases, but the speedup is not so remarkable, I think there must be something else I can do. BTW, `size_comp_buff` is decided by `size_in_buff`